# Excel IF formula with criteria based on structure of cell contents

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to arrange to have an IF condition based off the arrangement of text in a cell..

Pretty much I have a bunch of raw data pasted in excel from a web page where the column with the data I need is mixed in with useless text from the webpage.

The data I need is all just unit codes in 8 character alpha numeric form (eg. ASSA2125 PHOS1801)

To extract just the right data I was hoping to write a formula that tested the cell for either characters in that alphanumeric arrangement or perhaps tested for only 8 characters in the cell. eg =IF(J52=*AAAA2222*,J52,"")

Not sure if such a thing is possible, or if I just need to write the formula some type of way for excel to go looking for that...

Answer (score 1):

You can find string within string using `FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])` like this:

```
=FIND("ASSA2125",J52)
```

If there is no such sting within cell it will throw an `#VALUE!` error.
To catch this error you can use `ISERROR(value)` which returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
=ISERROR(FIND("ASSA2125",J52))
```

Now you can wrap this with an `IF()` statement:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("ASSA2125",J52)),"",J52)
```

Comment: @RobinMackenzie No you can't. `IFERROR()` will return the result of `FIND()` which is position of lookup string and `IF(ISERROR())` will return the contents of cell.

Answer (score 0):

Is using Google Spreadsheet an option for you? If yes you could use REGEXEXTRACT formula for that:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("ASSA2125", "[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}")
```

It would extract cells which content is *4 capital letters 4 digits*.

Comment: Not really.. This is part of a larger workbook that's for my team that's already built and I'm trying to set it up so it's as simple to use as possible.